# How to restore exported git repo in tar.gz format?

Tags: git

I have a repository which was exported and it is archived in `.tar.gz` format.
I searched online and solution everybody recommended to `git --bare clone` but it doesn't work for me.

Even though I have entire exported repo on my local machine, I get Permission Denied error.

Command I'm trying is...

```
git clone --bare repo.tar.gz
```

Comment: It a `git archive` or a pure zipped folder?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. You have a git archive - which mean that this is a read only repo.
   read more about it in here. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive
2. Its a pure `zip/tar` of a git repo - in this case simply untar/unzip it and that it.

In both cases you have to unzip/untar the content. the difference is that the second option is a pure GIT repo which allow you to continue working on the content while the first one is only a snapshot of the content.

Comment: Here's what it's directory structure looks like after I untar it.

`repo.git.tar.gz`
- repo.git.tar
-- repo.git
---github-backups
----repo.git
----- hooks
----- info
----- object
----- refs
----- config (file)
----- description (file)
----- HEAD (file)
----- packed-refs (file)
`

Comment: You'd better add it to question well formatted. As far as I understand this is content of .git directory. You should rename top directory of archive to `.git`, put it into an empty directory then run `git reset --hard` from it, to populate the files